# Windows 8.1 no longer recognize disk with a NTFS AND a ext4 ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, ntfs

So, as I do every 6 month, I installed a Ubuntu partition on my computer. I have a main SSD (C:) with Win8.1 on it and I had a secondary HDD (D:) with a single huge NTFS partition on it for my data. So, I used the Windows partition utility to free about 60GB for the Ubuntu install, keeping a 940GB NTFS partition with my data. Then, I used a boot drive to install Ubuntu and used the partition utility offered by the installer to separate he 60GB between a boot, a swap and a data partition. Ubuntu was finally installed.

I can boot ubuntu with grub, then access the HDD and see all the "windows" data on it (my music, files, etc.).

But when I boot on Windows, it no longer mounts the D: drive. Using the partition tool, I see that it lists the disk as "invalid". Again, I stress that the data is supposed to be in the NTFS format, as it was before, and that I am NOT trying to access Ubuntu (ext4) data in Windows.

Now, I had backups of my disk (hell, I can even access the data from Ubuntu), but if there is some ways to recover without having to erase everything...

Comment: could copy out the files in ubuntu, reformat it (in windows?) and move them back..

Comment: Yeah that's what I'll probably do (I am copying them right now) but if it is solvable in another way...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after having done another backup of my data, I went back to Windows. In the built in partition utility, the HDD was marked as an invalid drive. I right-clicked on it and choose... well I don't remember the exact wording, but it kind of re-mounted the drive. And instead of just formatting the drive, now I can see the three Ubuntu partition (boot, swap and home) and the ~900 GB unallocated space. So I just wiped out everything so I can put the data back on the disk.

So, unfortunately I didn't solve the issue the way I wanted, but at least I haven't lost anything but some time! ;)